# Draw the vector w as well as the projection of another vector onto w

Tags: matlab, vector, linear-algebra, matlab-figure, projection

How can I **plot** the vector **w** with the projected data onto this vector?
Here is the code - and my trials to plot the weight vector with **y1** and **y2**.

```
x1=[1 2;2 3;3 3;4 5;5 5]  % the first class 5 observations
x2=[1 0;2 1;3 1;3 2;5 3;6 5]
m1 = mean(x1); 
m2 = mean(x2); 
m = m1 + m2; 
d1=x1-repmat(m1,5,1);
d2=x2-repmat(m2,6,1);
c = 0.5.*m; 
Sw1 = d1'*d1;
Sw2 = d2'*d2;
Sw = Sw1 + Sw2; 
invSw = inv(Sw);
w= invSw*(m1-m2)' %this is my vector projected
scatter(x1(:,1), x1(:,2), 10, 'ro');
hold on;
scatter(x2(:,1), x2(:,2), 10,'bo');
%this is how i plot the decision boundary, but it doesn't seems correct. 
quiver(c(1,1), c(1,2), 1, -w(1,1)/w(2,1));
quiver(c(1,1), c(1,2), -1, w(1,1)/w(2,1));

auxw= w/norm(w);
plot([0 auxw(1)], [0 auxw(2)]) 
hold off;
figure; 
y1 = x1*w; 
y2 = x2*w; 
hist([y1' y2'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close.  You've only calculated (or tried to calculate) the scalar projection or the amount of scale you apply to each vector in order to project each vector in `x1` and `x2` onto `w` though what you have is incomplete. If you recall from linear algebra, to determine the scalar projection between two vectors `a` and `b`, or the scalar projection of `b` onto `a`, the formula is:

[image]

<sup>[Source: Oregon State Mathematics: Calculus for Undergraduates](http://math.oregonstate.edu/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/vcalc/dotprod/dotprod.html)</sup>

In our case, `a` would be `w` and `b` would be each of the vectors seen in `x1` and `x2`.  I'm assuming each row of these matrices is a vector. The scalar projections are seen in `y1` and `y2`.  You need to compute the **vector** projection, which is defined as taking the scalar projections and multiplying by the unit vectors of `a`, or simply:

[image]

<sup>[Source: Oregon State Mathematics: Calculus for Undergraduates](http://math.oregonstate.edu/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/vcalc/dotprod/dotprod.html)</sup>

Therefore, the calculation of the scalar projections in `y1` and `y2` are incorrect.  You have to multiply by the **normalized** vector `w`, then when you find these scalar projection values, you multiply each of these scalar values with the corresponding **normalized** vector `w`.  However, plotting these all simultaneously on a graph will be confusing.  You will have many lines that will overlap onto the original vector `w` so what I did was I looped through plotting `w`, a vector in either `x1` or `x2` and the corresponding projected vector.  Each time we loop, we pause and show the data then clear the figure and start again.

As such, I've added and changed the following to your code.

```
%// Your data
w = [-0.7936; 0.8899];
x1 = [1 2; 2 3; 3 3; 4 5; 5 5];
x2 = [1 0; 2 1; 3 1; 3 2; 5 3; 6 5];

%// Compute scalar projection
auxw = w/norm(w);
s1 = x1*auxw;
s2 = x2*auxw; %// Change for correctness

%// Compute the vector projection
y1 = bsxfun(@times, s1, auxw.');
y2 = bsxfun(@times, s2, auxw.');

%// Place the original vectors and corresponding projections
%// in one matrix
y = [y1; y2];
x = [x1; x2];

%// Loop through and plot w, a point in either x1 or x2
%// and the corresponding projection
for ii = 1 : size(y,1)
    plot([0 w(1)], [0 w(2)]);
    hold on;
    plot([0 y(ii,1)], [0 y(ii,2)], 'r');
    plot([0 x(ii,1)], [0 x(ii,2)], 'g');
    pause(0.5);
    clf;
end
```

The function [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) allows us to multiply each vector in `x1` and `x2` by their corresponding scalar values.  Specifically, it will take the vectors `s1` and `s2` and when we transpose `auxw` to be a `1 x 2` vector, we will create new matrices `y1` and `y2` where each row of either will compute the vector projections of `x1` and `x2` and place them into the rows of `y1` and `y2`.

The loop at the end cycles through `w`, a vector in either `x1` or `x2` and the corresponding projected vector one at a time and we pause for 0.5 seconds each time to see what the results look like. The vector `w` is in blue, the projected vector is in green and the original vector from either `x1` or `x2` is in red.

We get these series of figures:

[image]

We can see that the red line, which is the projected vector from either `x1` or `x2` onto `w`.  The green line is the original vector from either `x1` or `x2`.

Comment: . "You will have many lines that will overlap onto the original "

Comment: I should have only one line not multiple lines. I think you may review I was trying to do. The example is provided in this link. http://www.csd.uwo.ca/~olga/Courses/CS434a_541a/Lecture8.pdf

Comment: @ahmed_Mobile Your question was not clear.  I did not know you were trying to study Linear Discriminant Functions.  This to me looked like a purely algebraic question.  I'll delete my answer as it conflicts with what you want to do.

Comment: no please need to delete it. I'm still trying to know how plot the decision boundary between x1 and x2. I think I should scale the weighted vector w (projection) and I also should scale the line that is perpendicular on it. if you don't mind I will update my code, may be you could assist me better how to plot the decision boundary. It doesn't matter how LDA works. I have problem on how to plot the line

Comment: Which slide are you referring to? Which lines? I'm very confused.

Comment: If you click on the link provided, the example starts from page 19 to 21. At page 21, you will see that the equation of projecting the data into the line is a bit different from what you did. **Y1=c1'*w' and the same for Y2**. http://www.csd.uwo.ca/~olga/Courses/CS434a_541a/Lecture8.pdf